# Proper use of STREAM table and filter_key facebook FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

In the documentation it mention only AND and NOT.
The reason I'm trying to use OR is to break a large results sets into multiple queries and make sure the queries doesn't fail.

For example:
This query return one result:

> SELECT post_id FROM stream 
>   WHERE  (source_id = '100000462790227' ) AND strpos(lower(message),'sweet') >=0
>   AND (filter_key = 'others')

But when I added OR on the filter key I got empty results

> SELECT post_id FROM stream 
>   WHERE  (source_id = '100000462790227' ) AND strpos(lower(message),'sweet') >=0
>   AND (filter_key = 'others' OR filter_key = 'nf' )

Is it the OR, or do I do something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood what is the core issue.
Stream table filter_key 'other' and 'owner' works only on one source_id.
My original query had also OR on multiple source_id something like (source_id = '100000462790227' OR source_id = '12345670' ).

This combination return empty results!!

Comment: i'm trying some similar. i need to get posts from 2 source_id, but it is returning empty results. should I use filter_key in this case too?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my conclusions and observations:

First "OR" is supported by FQL.

One issue I saw "Graph API explorer" fails sometime while iOS SDK calls succeeded

If you limit the call with " LIMIT X" where X is under 100 you'll get an answer also on the second query. There are few posts on the issues related to large result set and what is the right limit (the one I read are all based on trial and error).